# Grouping by ID, where the same ID is used for different objects across multiple days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Date    ID  ObjAge
3-20    1   27
3-21    2   32
3-22    1   17
3-22    1   18
3-22    2   3
3-23    1   15
3-23    3   14
```

For each unique date, I would like to group together IDs within that date, where the maximum ObjAge of each ID within a given date is > 10. So, my ideal output table would look like this:

```
Date    ID  ObjAge
3-20    1   27
3-21    2   32
3-22    1   18
3-23    1   15
3-23    3   14
```

My example query looks like this:

```
SELECT [Date], ID, ObjAge,
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(ObjAge > 10);
```

When working with a single date, I would not have this issue. The issue is that an object's ID number for a certain day is also used for a different object ID on another day. Currently I am stuck with an error:

> [Date] is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Group by Date also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include into `group by` all selected columns(except aggregated ones). It will look like that :

```
SELECT [Date], ID, MAX(ObjAge)
FROM table1
GROUP BY  [Date],ID
HAVING MAX(ObjAge) > 10;
```

I believe for your case, this will also work :

```
SELECT [Date], ID, MAX(ObjAge)
FROM table1
Where ObjAge > 10
GROUP BY  [Date],ID;
```